# Why can't I use the $filter pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, version

I am trying to use the $filter pipeline in my mongodb search query, but I get this error `{ MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$filter'` I am sure it has to do with my version of mongodb which is the latest, but for some reason still don't have access to the [filter aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

package.json

```
{
    "mongodb": "^3.0.1",
    "mongojs": "^2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.7"
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you are using the `$filter` pipeline operator?

Comment: Can you add the document and on which field of the document you tried to apply the $filter. Your error, could be due to many things. Maybe you use it in the wrong pipeline

Comment: Which version of MongoDB you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) is an operator. The error suggests you are using it as a [stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

What you need to filter documents, you can use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage, and if you actually need to filter an array within a document, you should use it within a valid stage, e.g. [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

As a side note, `package.json` defines versions of javascript driver and libraries,   not the database itself.